# PHP mail script does not send mail

Tags: php, email

I have this mail script on my page: `mail('myadress@server.com', 'New client added by user', 'test message');`
but I do not receive anything! (of course I added my real adress). I tried it with 2 different adresses, looked in my spam folder, etc... just nothing. but the script executes just fine.

Is there any log I can view or invoke to see exactly what happened?

thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bemail%5D+not+sending

Comment: nope couldn't find how to log my php email activity

Comment: Need more info. What's your hosting situation? Last time this happened to me it was because I upgraded to Windows 7 and didn't have a mail server installed.

Comment: maybe it is not using as sender the address you need.. did you try to use the 4th parameter adding "From: sender@server.com".. or maybe the 5th parameter also using -f and the same address "-f sender@server.com"

Comment: I'm working on a crappy dedicated server with no access to any settings whatsoever... It's basic LAMP. In my admin panel there is no info to be found...

Comment: are you checking return from mail() function? it should return true if  successful

Comment: @hummingBird how wuld I do that? mail('...'); echo mail() return;. EDIT, no just echo mail(); right? let me try

Comment: no that was stupid, doesn't work

Comment: try something like `$out = mail(...); echo ($out ? 'true' : 'false');`... if echo mail() doesn't return anything, it might mean you're getting `false` in return, which doesn't display on screen

Comment: hi, im experienceing the same issue as this, php mail not sending. php mail return a success message but the email is not really being delivered to the recipient. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add the header "from" and use an email adress created on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$to = "someone@example.com";

$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";

$from = "someonelse@example.com";


$headers = "From:" . $from;


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";

?>
```

try this it will going to work for u ....

Answer (score 0):

1) Check the return value from the mail() call:

```
$status = mail(...);
if (!$status) {
    die("Mail failed");
}
```

If this fails, then PHP cannot even get the mail out the front door, and you'll have to figure out why - e.g. are you on a Windows box and haven't configured the mail options in php.ini?

2) Check your mail server's logs. Most Unix/Linux systems have a local mail server (the MTA) which will accept the mail from PHP. If it's misconfigured or having trouble, it may still accept the mail from PHP but then leave the mail to rot in a queue.

Perhaps your server's been placed on spam blackhole lists and it simply cannot deliver mail anywhere, which means you've probably got all of your test mails stuck in an outgoing queue that can't go anywhere.